# Как получить данные из столбца mysql с типом данных enum средствами java?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

В базе данных в таблице `data` есть столбец `users` с типом данных enum, в котором содержится перечисление.
Как получить данные из этого столбца?

Пример запроса:

```
String sql = "SELECT `users` FROM data WHERE `name`=?";
PreparedStatement stmt = connect().prepareStatement(sql);
stmt.setString(1, user.toLowerCase());
ResultSet result = stmt.executeQuery();
if(result.next(){
    result.getЧТО-ТО()
}
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, с выводом данных.

Comment: Такой же вопрос, только ответ в английской версии: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/656688/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-enum-jdbc-mysql-java

Comment: также интересно, как вписать данные в столбец типа enum

Comment: Тоже хороший вопрос, но лучше задать его отдельно, т.к. здесь Вам уже ответили.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так

```
while ( result.next() ) {
  String users = result.getString("users");
  System.out.println(users);
}
```